# What are the image sizes for custom Visual Studio 2010 templates?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm making a custom template for Visual Studio 2010. In the .vstemplate file, I can specify images for `<Icon>` and `<PreviewImage>`. What are the sizes of these images?

Comment: Use arbitrary, build, deploy, see how it looks in VS and measure the actual sizes.

Comment: That's what I did. However, I would like something a bit more precise than just trial and error.

Answer (score 5):

There are three sizes respectively:

**Icon image**

- 16x16 pixels for the if the Small Icons option is selected for
  listing project templates.
- 32x32 pixels if the Medium Icons option is    selected.

**Preview image**

200x200 pixels regardless the size of the image you specify.

For more, see a post of mine: https://dolinkamark.wordpress.com/2015/03/10/how-to-create-a-visual-studio-2013-project-template/

Which I know is about vs 2013, however it applies to previous versions if my memory serves. And unfortunately as you have written in your comment, these conclusions for image sizes and types are from trial and error as I haven't found any specifications on MSDN about this.

Comment: These sizes appear to be the same in VS2015 (by measuring the icons and preview images of built-in templates from a screenshot of the project dialog).

Answer (score 1):

The default template icon (__TemplateIcon.ico) for Visual Studio 2015 has the following modes (used Microangelo Studio to find out):

- 256x256 32 bit colors (XP) (which includes alpha channel), with PNG compression
- 256x256 8 bit colors (256), with PNG compression
- 64x64 32 bit colors (XP), no compression
- 48x48 32 bit colors (XP), no compression
- 48x48 8 bit colors (256), no compression
- 32x32 32 bit colors (XP), no compression
- 32x32 8 bit colors (256), no compression
- 16x16 32 bit colors (XP), no compression
- 16x16 8 bit colors (256), no compression

The default colors are:
front: 66, 66, 66 (hex: 424242)
backdrop: 246, 246, 246 (hex: f6f6f6)

Seems the 'Dark theme' repaints the icon somehow

Answer (score 0):

Here are my empirical approach to this issue:

- Icons size used into the item template selection wizard are 32x32 pixels (ICO format).
- PreviewImage are placed centered without cropping or scrolling if the image keeps itself under 200x380 pixels (PNG format). Note: vertical size also depends on how many text you enter as description.

Sizes seems similar in VS2010 & VS212.